# How to Update Employee and Identity User with one to one/zero relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update employee record and want to update identity user too.

If i update Identity User first separately 
For Example:

```
UserManager.Update(user);
Context.Entry(employee).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
Context.SaveChanges();
```

and then update the employee.
maybe it is possible identity user updates with success but employee update process gets an error. 
so `IdentityUser` is updated now but the employee is not.
how to handle this situation.
please guide.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public string AppUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AppUserId")]
    public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<string, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>, IUser<string>
{
        public AppUser()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
            GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<AppUser, string> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager
                .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

```
public JsonResult Create(EmployeeVM evm, AppUserVM appUser)
{
    var jsonResult = new JsonResult();
    jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          var user = new AppUser();
          evm.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
          appUser.PasswordHash = "dummypass";
          user = Mapper.Map<AppUser>(appUser);
          var employee = Mapper.Map<Employee>(evm);
          employee.AppUser = user;
          try
           {
                if (userService.CreateEmployee(employee))
                   {
                        jsonResult.Data = new { Success = true, message = "Success Added Record"};
                   }
            }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {

                jsonResult.Data = new { Success = false, message =ex.Message};
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jsonResult.Data = new { Success = false, message = ModelErrors() };
        }

    return jsonResult;
}
```

```
public bool CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    Context.Employees.Add(employee);
    return Context.SaveChanges()>0;
}
```

Adding new record works fine.
but when i update the record. i don't know how to update both records at once.
For Example:

```
public JsonResult Edit(EmployeeVM evm, AppUserVM appUserVM)
{
            ModelState.Remove(nameof(evm.CreatedDate));
            var jsonResult = new JsonResult();
            jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                appUserVM.UserName = appUserVM.Email;
                var user = UserManager.FindById(evm.UserId);
                user.Email      = appUserVM.Email;
                user.UserName      = appUserVM.UserName;
                user.FirstName  = appUserVM.FirstName;
                user.LastName      = appUserVM.LastName;
                user.IsActive   = appUserVM.IsActive;
                user.PhoneNumber   = appUserVM.PhoneNumber;
                var employee = Mapper.Map<Employee>(evm);
                employee.AppUser = user;
                employee.Id = evm.Id;
                employee.AppUserId = user.Id;
                try
                {
                    if(userService.UpdateEmployee(employee))
                        jsonResult.Data = new { Success = true, message = "Success" };
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    jsonResult.Data = new { Success = false, message = ex.Message };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                jsonResult.Data = new { Success = false, message = ModelErrors() };
            }

   return jsonResult;
}
```

```
public bool UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    Context.Entry(employee).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    return Context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

Comment: can you add the exception?

Comment: If that these are on the same `DbContext`, then update employee first, then update the user - these will be wrapped into the same transaction by EF inside of `SaveChanges` that is called by `UserManager`. If different DbContext, then create a transaction yourself va `using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)){ /* your updates here */ }`

Comment: I am using same Db Context which is inherited with IdentityDbContext.
But i am little confused while using User Manager

```
public AppUserManager UserManager
{
   get
     {
         return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<AppUserManager>();
}
private set
{
userManager = value;
}
}
```
using UserManager with GetOwinContext().Get<AppUserManager>();
is this same Context?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the exception, I'm not sure what the issue is, but you could trying using an attached entity and set values like the following.

```
 var dbEmployee = Context.Emplyoees.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == employee.Id);
 if (dbEmployee!= null)
 Context.Entry(dbEmployee).CurrentValues.SetValues(employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

The User employee service should be

```
public bool UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    var existingEmployee = Context.Emplyoees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == employee.Id);
    if (existingEmployee != null)
    {
        //do the update to the database 
        Context.Entry(existingEmployee).CurrentValues.SetValues(employee);
        Context.Entry(existingEmployee).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        return Context.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Employee and IdentityUser have one to one/zero relation 
i want to update employee record and identityUser record at once..
will your given code update Employee and IdentityUser record?

Comment: I edited base on your code.  UserManager.Update(user); will update the user and the abouve function will update the employee after the user, if you want to update both at the same time look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692042/insert-users-id-into-multiple-tabels-using-mvc-identity/55696493#55696493 to see how you can link both table and update at the same time