# Entity Framework certain values of object missing after update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but I have an Index view where the user can change all the records at once. The data is passing into the HttpPost properly and I can parse my JSON object correctly (I'm doing some Javascript actions on the front end that make it necessary to pass the data back as a JSON object), but when I return the view after the save, the `title` value of my object in my recently updated object is missing. If I refresh the page after the save, the `title` value returns (so it wasn't lost). Am I missing a step after my `SaveChanges` call that would reload/refresh the Entity object?

**Model**

```
[Key]
public int InventoryItemID { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Inventory Category")]
public int InventoryCategoryID { get; set; }
public virtual InventoryCategory Category { get; set; }
public int Lifespan { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Cost"),
DataType(DataType.Currency),
DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "-",
               ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
               DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
public decimal Cost { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Index(IFormCollection postedData)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        List<InventoryItem> items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InventoryItem>>(postedData["itemsJSON"]);
        foreach (InventoryItem i in items)
        {
            _context.InventoryItems.Attach(i);
            var entry = _context.Entry(i);
            entry.Property("InventoryCategoryID").IsModified = true;
            entry.Property("Lifespan").IsModified = true;
            entry.Property("Cost").IsModified = true;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    var inventory = _context.InventoryItems.Include(i => i.Category);
    //THIS LIST IS MISSING THE item.title VARIABLE FOR ALL ITEMS THAT WERE JUST UPDATED :-(
    return View(inventory.ToList());
}
```

As I said, the `inventory` var comes back missing the `title` value. Since I am making a fresh call with `var inventory = _context.InventoryItems.Include(i => i.Category);`, shouldn't this return recently-updated data from the database? If I refresh the index page, the `title` value is there, but I can not see this value until I perform a page refresh. I feel like I'm missing a fundamental principle, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: By the title returned do you mean the changes were not committed? Again is it an update or you are making a new insert? Your question title is a little bit confusing. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982875/how-to-update-employee-and-identity-user-with-one-to-one-zero-relation/55987634#55987634) for updating, basically you need to get the previous data by an Id or something before updating it.

Comment: Well, apparently, `items` contains `InventoryItem` without `Title`. After `SaveChanges` the empty titles are still the current values, i.e. no overwritten by the query, but not saved because they weren't marked as modified.