# How to add extra fields to AspNetUsers Table and Insert into it using ASP.NET webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a project that I created, I have added Identity, Entity Framework and Owin, I am able to register users, I am able to login.

The challenge is that, I would like to add other fields such as First name, RoleId, Gender etc to the `ASPNETUser` table.
I added the columns manually from the DB but I can't access them from the code, I would like to be able to insert into the new columns when registering a new user

I am using Webforms and not MVC, how do I achieve this?
Thank you

I have tried adding the columns as classes in the public class `ApplicationUser` : `IdentityUser` and I can access it but the columns are still missing in the db cause I had to delete them as well.

```cs
public class IdentityModels
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
      GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager
                .CreateIdentityAsync(this,
                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Gender { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692042/insert-users-id-into-multiple-tabels-using-mvc-identity/55696493#55696493